# Some questions on building Neo4j with Maven

Tags: java, maven, build, neo4j

I'm doing a project with neo4j. I need to modify some lines of code because I want it to work differently than usual.

So it's necessary for me to build it with this command:

`mvn clean install -DfullBuild`

I'm new to Maven. I don't understand some things:

- Why do Maven download some files while building? I just want to compile my code, is there any reason to download anything?
- Is there any way to avoid compiling/running tests? Some of them fail when changing code and the build fails. And documentation? How can I avoid generating it?
- Why does it take sooo long to build? Every time I change a line it takes me like 30 minutes to build it again. I just want to compile some modules instead of all of them.
- I've seen that some modules has their own pom.xml file. Does it mean that I can build them separately to save time?

Thanks for any help given!

Answer (score 2):

1) it's downloading all the dependencies (which are a lot). If you have snapshot dependencies they will be redownloaded on a daily basis.

2) add `-DskipTests=true` to your command line arguments

3) most of the build time is spent running the tests. Neo4j has a strict focus on quality hence a lot of tests. Also building the browser requires couple of steps to compress/package javascript, css and other stuff.

4) yes. If you change something in submodule xyz, just call `mvn install -DskipTests=true` from within that module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In 4) may I use `mvn compile` instead of install?

Comment: you can call any maven command in any subdirectories - maybe read the manual at http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html